# Drupal - Using a frame to display custom php / javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, drupal

I've created a custom file for a google-maps that uses javascript, php, and SQL statements. Instead of building a module, is it possible to just simply create a frame for `page--front.tpl.php` to display my file for the google map?

Comment: Have you tried it out to see if it works?

Comment: Do you want to know if it is possible or how would you do it? It's definitely possible, just not really the ideal way.

Comment: Yeah I'm interested in knowing how I can do something like that... I've been sort of ripping my hair out the whole last month trying to figure out how to simply/quickly implement my map code in my front page without a frame, but basically am throwing in the towel because of how uneasy of a feat it seems to be (for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic implementation of the iframe would be:

```
<iframe src="/map_script.php" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

Where map_script.php would be your custom map file and you would place it in the root of your website.

If you didn't want the file in the root of your website but in your theme instead it would be:

```
<iframe src="/sites/all/themes/theme_name/map_script.php" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

Changing the path to suit your site's file structure and theme name.

Of course you can change the width and height or play around with any of the iframe attributes.
For more information on what you can do with the iframe tag see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

You can put that iframe tag wherever you want the map to print in your page--front.tpl.php file.